# The Comforting Death Message

Tags: word-problem, lateral-thinking, rebus

Linda sadly passes away in a stampede of elephants and when she reaches St. Peter, she is distressed because she doesn't think she'll be buried properly on the family grave plot and having to listen to her mother complain about her not being buried beside her will make even eternal paradise unenjoyable. However, on explaining her distress to St. Peter he smiles knowingly and hands her a card which he says is from Linda's husband back on the ground <sub>(no, he doesn't explain how, put your hand down)</sub>

The card has 6 words on it, Linda reads it and smiles and enters Heaven assured that her husband will ensure she is buried properly.

There are 3 words on the top line and 3 words underneath but there are only 5 unique words. The words are 'taking', 'take', 'to', 'your' and 'I'. What does the card say and therefore what is the message?

Hint

> The repeated word is take.

Hint 2:

> The words are layed out as follows: 
>  ____________
>  ____________
> and the layout of the words are integral to the solution being correct

As usual please place your answers in spoiler tags.

<sub>As a side note, I'm not in any way religious (total atheist), however I needed a setting involving a dead person receiving a message from a living loved one, so this sprang to mind. It was not my intention to mock any religious beliefs/values/ideals/concepts held by anyone.</sub>

Comment: Usually, everything unrelated to elephants is irrelephant, but in this case, are they themselves, relephant?

Comment: Not at all, simply a convenient method of death.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I've seen a variation of this before:

> `Take   to    Taking`
>  `I     see     Your`
>
>  Which reads as "I undertake to oversee your undertaking". You don't allow the word "see" but I assume it's a variation of that....?

Comment: Exactly right. Although I was given the answer I undertake to overtake (as in take over, didn't make much sense to me at the time either) your undertaking. But now I know oversee, I shall use that from now on. Add <br/> to force a line break in your answer.

Comment: This is quite a strange thing for a grieving husband to write!

Comment: Yes, in the original version that I saw many, many years ago, it was "undertakings" in the sense of "business" rather than "burying people" so it was somewhat less macabre. It also had 8 words which may have been, "I understand you undertake to oversee my undertakings".